# Using Apache::Session::Memcached with MasonX::Request::WithApacheSession

Tags: perl, memcached, mod-perl, mason

I'm trying to use [Apache::Session::Memcached](http://search.cpan.org/~enrys/Apache-Session-Memcached-0.03/lib/Apache/Session/Memcached.pm) in an [HTML::Mason](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/HTML-Mason-1.42/lib/HTML/Mason.pm) project where I'm using [MasonX::Request::WithApacheSession](http://search.cpan.org/~blhotsky/MasonX-Request-WithApacheSession-0.31/lib/MasonX/Request/WithApacheSession.pm) to handle my sessions.  Unfortunately Apache will not launch when I plug in the Memcached module instead of the MySQL one.  My custom handler looks something like this (a few snips here and there):

```
my $ah = HTML::Mason::ApacheHandler->new (
    comp_root                   =>  $ENV{HTDOCS},
    data_dir                    =>  $data_dir,
    request_class               =>  'MasonX::Request::WithApacheSession',
    session_use_cookie          =>  0,
    args_method                 =>  "mod_perl",
    session_args_param          =>  'session_id',
    session_class               =>  'Apache::Session::Memcached',
    session_Servers             =>  '127.0.0.1:20000',
    session_Readonly            =>  0,
    session_Debug               =>  1,
    session_cookie_domain       =>  $CONF->{global}->{site_name},
    session_cookie_expires      =>  "session",
    session_allow_invalid_id    =>  0,                                          
    );
```

The problem I'm running into is that the `session_*` paramaters specific to Memcached are not being passed through to [Apache::Session::Memcached](http://search.cpan.org/~enrys/Apache-Session-Memcached-0.03/lib/Apache/Session/Memcached.pm) like [the docs say it should](http://search.cpan.org/~blhotsky/MasonX-Request-WithApacheSession-0.31/lib/MasonX/Request/WithApacheSession.pm#CONFIGURATION).  This results in this error:

```
The following parameter was passed in the call to HTML::Mason::ApacheHandler->new()
but was not listed in the validation options: session_Servers
```

Now, I have gone through and swapped all of the 3 upper case arguments to lower case, to no avail.  And [the docs](http://search.cpan.org/~enrys/Apache-Session-Memcached-0.03/lib/Apache/Session/Memcached.pm) for [Apache::Session::Memcached](http://search.cpan.org/~enrys/Apache-Session-Memcached-0.03/lib/Apache/Session/Memcached.pm) list them as upper case.

Thanks a ton for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need to register Apache::Session::Memcached with Apache::Session::Wrapper, following the instructions at http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Apache::Session::Wrapper#REGISTERING_CLASSES like so (code courtesy Jack M.):

```
Apache::Session::Wrapper::->RegisterClass(
    'name' => 'Apache::Session::Memcached',
    'required' => [ [ 'Servers' ], ],
    'optional' => [ 'NoRehash', 'Readonly', 'Debug', 'CompressThreshold', ],
);
```

Comment: You, sir/madam are the man/woman!  I've been wracking myself on this one.  I don't have the rep to edit your post, but you should throw this in there:
    Apache::Session::Wrapper->RegisterClass(
            name => 'Apache::Session::Memcached',
            required => [ [ 'Servers' ], ],
            optional => [ 'NoRehash', 'Readonly', 'Debug', 'CompressThreshold', ],
        );